# SSL - SecurityContext - Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file - Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2

Tags: file, ssl, flutter, filesystemexception

When I try to set certificate, I get an error:

```
E/flutter ( 7195): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/ssl/STAR_octopusspace_com.crt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) E/flutter ( 7195): #0 _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:643:7) E/flutter ( 7195): #1 _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:487:5) E/flutter ( 7195): #2 _File.readAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:547:18) E/flutter ( 7195): #3 _SecurityContext.useCertificateChain (dart:io/runtime/binsecure_socket_patch.dart:175:40)
```

and this is how my code looks like:
[image: a busy cat]

I'm not sure where should I put my files.
Any ideas?

I have declared ssl folder in my yaml file.

```
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
      - assets/ssl/
      - assets/graphics/
```

**UPDATE:**

Changed code to this:

```
    final List<int> certificateChainBytes =
        (await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl/STAR_octopusspace_com.crt')).buffer.asInt8List();
    context.useCertificateChainBytes(certificateChainBytes);
    final List<int> keyBytes =
    (await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl/client_octopusspace.key')).buffer.asInt8List();
    context.usePrivateKeyBytes(keyBytes);
```

but now I get this error:

> E/flutter (11733): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: TlsException: Failure in usePrivateKeyBytes (OS Error: E/flutter (11733): KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH(ssl_cert.cc:494), errno = 0) E/flutter (11733): #0 _SecurityContext.usePrivateKeyBytes (dart:io/runtime/binsecure_socket_patch.dart:164:50)

Comment: I'd use `asUint8List`, but that may not make any difference. Your private key is probably password protected (it should be). Provide the password as the second parameter to `usePrivateKeyBytes`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
final SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

final ByteData crtData = await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl/STAR_octopusspace_com.crt');
context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(crtData.buffer.asUint8List());

final ByteData authoritiesBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl/STAR_octopusspace_com.ca-bundle');
context.setClientAuthoritiesBytes(authoritiesBytes.buffer.asUint8List());

final ByteData keyBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/ssl/client_octopusspace.key');
context.usePrivateKeyBytes(keyBytes.buffer.asUint8List());

httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);
```

Thanks everyone :)